# grin, ack and rak comparison

Tags: grep, ack

Having used [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) for some time now, I find it much better for my development purposes than grep. But then I've heard about [rak](http://rak.rubyforge.org/) and [grin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin). Has anyone used all three of them and can provide a comparison?

Comment: related question (contains links to similar posts on SO): http://superuser.com/questions/39384/best-grep-like-tool

Comment: that's the place where I've learned about grin and rake. Still it doesn't compare these tools. I want to know whether it's worth to make an effort and try out grin and rak.

Comment: I guess the answer is settled for now. Use the silver searcher aka ag. It's fast! and has sane defaults.

Comment: Related: [Software to search through your own libraries of source code?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13190/3474)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For people still looking at this question:

At this point you should probably use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Answer (score -1):

As the [rak](http://rak.rubyforge.org/) website says, rak is a Ruby grep-like tool based on [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/). [grin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin) is a Python grep-like tool also based on ack.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **The Silver Searcher**. Here is [project page](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/). It is really fast.